# Parsing request.body to string then create JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I am stuck on parsing out a string right now into a json type. I've gotten the request body down to the string but cant seem to parse the data out correctly.

What I have:

```
String to parse:
uniq1.data.data.data 7 bleep\nuniq2.data.data.data 4 boop\nuniq3.data.data.data 7 bleep\ntets4.data.data.data 7 bleep\nuniq5.data.data.data 7 bleep\ntest6.data.data.data 7 fgws
```

Would like to make the string into JSON that has the following stucture so I can insert it into a mongoose db:

```
name: uniq1
typeID: 7
type: bleep

name: uniq2
typeID: 4
type: boop

name: tets4
typeID: 7
type: bleep
```

Currently I am trying to replace all of the '\n' new lines with commas so I can parse the data out using commas but when I do the bodyText.replace( new RegExp( "\n", "g" ),",") nothing in the string changes. I'm also thinking there is probably a better way to go about this that I'm not thinking of.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this-

```js
let str = "uniq1.data.data.data 7 bleep\nuniq2.data.data.data 4 boop\nuniq3.data.data.data 7 bleep\ntets4.data.data.data 7 bleep\nuniq5.data.data.data 7 bleep\ntest6.data.data.data 7 fgws";


const arr = str.split("\n");

const json = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 const [first, typeID, type] = curr.split(" ");
 const [name] = first.split('.');
 
 acc.push({name: name, typeID, type});

 return acc;
}, []);

console.log(json);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

**Note:** I've found something like `bleep\uniq5` instead of `bleep\nuniq5`. If the `request.body` sends you exactly this then you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Sajeeb, I gave it a shot and my "type" results are "the following: type: 'bleep\\nuniq1.data.data.data' } ] it looks like the split isnt working for some reason. Also I only have 1 element in the logged json. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please share the exact string?

Comment: I cant share the exact string because of the data it has but it looks exactly like this I just replaced the fields with the word data1/2/3/4: data1.data2.data3.data4 7 ltm_apm\ndata1.data2.data3.data4 4 full\ndata1.data2.data3.data4 7 ltm_apm\ndata1.data2.data3.data4 7 ltm_apm\ndata1.data2.data3.data4\ndata1.data2.data3.data4 7 ltm_apm

Comment: I think has something to do with the find of /n if I past the string in your function is working fine but something is happening to the string to possibly create a //n

Comment: Yes that works I updated the code with nBody.replace("\\n\"}", ""); and it works :). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = "uniq1.data.data.data 7 bleep\nuniq2.data.data.data 4 boop\nuniq3.data.data.data 7 bleep\ntets4.data.data.data 7 bleep\nuniq5.data.data.data 7 bleep\ntest6.data.data.data 7 fgws";
const b = a.split("\n");
const c = b.map((el) => el.split(" "));
const d = c.map(([name, typeID, type]) => {
  return { name, typeID, type };
});
console.log(d);
```

`b` splits the body into lines.
`c` splits each line into an array divided by each space.
`d` maps the array of each line into the object with the keys.

I changed the input a bit. `\uniq5` this part looks inconsistent and I think it should be \nuniq5.